# Android JSOUP ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: android, jsoup

I updated my dex classes with amigo library (it's changing one apk for another apk with the same key and signature, all is working except JSOUP)

Error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1567
>                                                      Process: com.smedic.tubtub, PID: 26102
>                                                      java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>                                                          at org.jsoup.nodes.Document$OutputSettings.(Document.java:372)
>                                                          at org.jsoup.nodes.Document.(Document.java:19)
>                                                          at org.jsoup.parser.TreeBuilder.initialiseParse(TreeBuilder.java:32)
>                                                          at org.jsoup.parser.TreeBuilder.parse(TreeBuilder.java:42)
>                                                          at org.jsoup.parser.HtmlTreeBuilder.parse(HtmlTreeBuilder.java:56)
>                                                          at org.jsoup.parser.Parser.parseInput(Parser.java:32)
>                                                          at org.jsoup.helper.DataUtil.parseByteData(DataUtil.java:104)
>                                                          at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.parse(HttpConnection.java:666)
>                                                          at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:225)
>                                                          at com.power.mati.VideosAdapter$4.run(VideosAdapter.java:177)
>                                                          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>                                                       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not read resource
>   entities-xhtml.properties. Make sure you copy resources for
>   org.jsoup.nodes.Entities
>                                                          at org.jsoup.nodes.Entities.load(Entities.java:289)
>                                                          at org.jsoup.nodes.Entities.access$000(Entities.java:25)
>                                                          at org.jsoup.nodes.Entities$EscapeMode.(Entities.java:48)

Any idea how to fix it?

I am using jars and maven, same situation.

Comment: Yes, I experienced the same problem but I noticed that the jar only gave this error after I used Proguard

Answer (score 22):

I saw something similar and my solution is in proguard

```
-keep class org.jsoup.**
```

Comment: I am using 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.3' and implementing this great tip didn't solve the issue for me. I guess I will need to add @Sai's update as well.

Answer (score 4):

Update the library, use this one :

implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.13.1'

Your problem will be resolved...

Comment: This, along with implementing @LouisTsai answer, indeed solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

add Jsoup library in libs folder and add -keep class org.jsoup.** in your proguard-rules.pro file.

Then it will work.

Answer (score -2):

in my case, my problem is solved by turning minifyEnabled to false in the app's build.gradle, this will keep all classes in the final release apk.

```
android {
....
    buildTypes {
...
        release {
            minifyEnabled false

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Turning off proguard to fix the problem is not a valid solution

Comment: but its the only one it help me out in my case, if you have one put it.